# Picking up correct version of configuration file when running within IDE

Tags: spring, maven

Our Spring application is built using maven, which creates a zip which is extracted to disk.

One of the files in the application is a configuration file, which, when the application is run, needs to live in a directory on the file system similar to the following:

```
application-root
   config
```

There are different versions of the file for different environments.
To cope with this, we have different folders under `config`, each with its own file:

```
application-root
   config
      prod
      uat
      sit
      dev
```

After the zip is extracted to disk, we move the file from the appropriate environment sub directory one level up into the `config` directory.
All this works great.

In order to run from within IntelliJ, we need to have a version of the configuration file in the `config` folder.

What I have done is simply to copy the file from the `dev` folder and placed it into the `config` folder. Although the file is in version control, it is not included in the assembly build, so does not get included in the zip.

The question is, is there a better way to do this?
Is there a way to setup the build, or to configure within Spring, so that when the applications runs within the IDE, it will automatically look at the file in the `dev` folder, within our needing to make a copy of it?